# Why contract.on(filter,...) returns [object Object] when listening to events?

Tags: solidity, ether, dapps, ethereumjs

In javascript:

```
const info_contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);
      const info = info_contract.connect(signer);
let instructorFilter = info.filters.Instructor(null, null);
    info.on(instructorFilter, (_name, _age) => {
      $("#info").html(_name + ' (' + _age + ' years old)' )
    });
```

In solidity:

```
contract InfoContract{
    string name;
    uint age;
    
    event Instructor(string indexed _name,uint indexed _age);
    
    function setInfo(string memory _name,uint _age) public {
        name = _name;
        age = _age;
        emit Instructor(_name , _age);
    }
    
    function getInfo() public view returns (string memory,uint){
        return (name,age);
    }
}
```

while I setInfo to the contract,"_name" was changed,but it shows [object Object] but not the string of "_name",but the age is correct.How can resolve it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

JS does not see `_name` as a string.

```
JSON.stringify(_name);
```